# Unity Shader Graph - How to Change Parameters --- How to change a parameter of a mesh on all objects at the same time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-shaders

I created my first shader by following this video. [Dissolve Shader Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NuesGD0msI)

In a Coroutine,i took the Material's component from the object:

```
PalaceMaterial = palaceInstance.GetComponent <Renderer> () .material;
```

I set the parameter to 0:

```
PalaceMaterial.SetFloat ("_ CutoffHeight", 0);
```

To have this effect, I had to modify the parameter "CuttoffHeight" gradually
putting it in Update ()

```
 PalaceMaterial.SetFloat("_CutoffHeight", Mathf.MoveTowards(PalaceMaterial.GetFloat("_CutoffHeight"), CutoffHeight, 100 * Time.deltaTime));
```

I applied this to all objects.
Every 2 seconds i instantiate an "invisible object" (CutoffHeight
set to 0)
and in Update() it change the value gradually.
Now I would like to change this parameter to all objects that use this shader simultaneously.
I hope i was clear.

Video of my project :
[Project](https://streamable.com/gpoymc), [Dissolve_Effect](https://streamable.com/60a73v)

I would like to change the "_CutoffHeight" parameter simultaneously in all the cubes that are in the first platform, then in the second one, etc. etc.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you shouldn't additionally use `GetFloat` but rather store the value locally and calculate it from there.

---

Then this already should work if multiple objects share the exact same material by using e.g.

```
GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.SetFloat(...);
```

but this works only as long as you don't have multiple instances of the material in your renderers.

---

There is a way to set a property for **all Shaders** (which have that property) and their according instances (= Materials) I came across in [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/global-variables-in-the-shader-graph-urp-lwrp.820413/)

To do this you have to

- **Disable** "exposed" for the according property. Apparently it only works for properties that are not exposed in the Inspector.
- Use the generated shader property ID you can find in the Inspector of the shader asset itself.

  You can also retrieve it using [`Shader.PropertyToID`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Shader.PropertyToID.html)

  You can also change it to match your actual parameter name.
- Use the global setter methods of the shader like [`Shader.SetGlobalXY`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Shader.SetGlobalFloat.html)

[image]

e.g. in order to set the `Spec Brightness` you would do

```
Shader.SetGlobalFloat("Vector1_DD757871", value);
```

---

So in your case you could probably have one single controller doing something like

```
// Need this only if you have to get the initial value once
[SerializeField] private Material PalaceMaterial;

private float currentValue;
private string propertyId;

private void Awake()
{
    propertyId = Shader.PropertyToID("_CutoffHeight");
    currentValue = PalaceMaterial.GetFloat("_CutoffHeight");
}

private void Update()
{
    currentValue = Maths.MoveTowards(currentValue, CutoffHeight, 100 * Time.deltaTime);
    Shader.SetGlobalFloat(propertyId, currentValue);
}
```

Comment: I would like to instantiate  ex 20 cubes every 10 seconds.
These cubes use the shader we are talking about here. I would like to change the shader's parameter only to the first 20 cubes, after 10 seconds, to the other 20.
What you said is very interesting, but I can't use it, thanks anyway.
My English is not very good. Sorry :)

Comment: Oh but then what speaks against using something like `foreach(var instance in spawnedInstances) { instance.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetFloat(...); }`?

Comment: I added videos, I hope you can understand what I want to do.